# Mediawiki API-Login doesn't log in the User

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

My Website has users with passwords. On my Website i have a button that should login automatically to the wiki using a simple (invisible) form automatically filled with the same usernames and passwords. So the users don't realize the second login. 
The Button links to a script that performs a "succesfull" login via API (the log says "PASS" + username). After succesfull login i redirect to the mainpage `header("Location: Mainpage")`
But nobody is logged in.

It feels like only the server itself (through the script) is logging in, but not the person, who is klicking the button. Could that be the reason?

How to solve this? My Mediawiki is v. 1.27
(Have already tried writing an own AuthenticationProvider, but it's to highlevel for me)

Comment: You need to set the right cookies for the user, which is how websites keep track of logged-in state. If your wiki and website are on the same domain, you can do this by making your script forward `Cookie` and `Set-Cookie` headers, although it's inadvisable and probably insecure. A `PrimaryAuthenticationProvider` or `SessionProvider` would be the proper solution (the first is probably easier to write).

Comment: Unfortunately there are on different servers